# Aligning a table inside a basedescript

Tags: tables, lists, mdwtools, basedescript

I'm using a `tabular` inside a `basedescript` enviroment from the `mdwlist` package.
I need to have "normal paragraph"-like behaviour on both sides — so LaTeX will wrap lines and break words.

The vertical alignment of the table doesn't fit the one of the label. I worked around it using `\vspace{}` trying to approach the same height.

**Is there a proper way to achieve this?**

---

Problem (red circle) and workaround solution:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{basedescript}{%
\desclabelstyle{\multilinelabel}
\desclabelwidth{3cm}}
\item[some label]
   dummy text

    \item[another label ]
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
      line 1 & row 2 \\
      line 2 & row 2 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{basedescript}


\hrule
\subsubsection*{workaround with \\vspace }

\begin{basedescript}{%
\desclabelstyle{\multilinelabel}
\desclabelwidth{3cm}}
\item[some label]
   dummy text

    \item[another label ]
    ~\vspace{-1.3em}

    \begin{tabular}{lr}
      line 1 & row 2 \\
      line 2 & row 2 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{basedescript}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{tabular}[t]{lr}` to get top alignment of the the `tabular` content

Comment: Turns out, it was an error on my side. I tried `[t]` before but didn't get the result I wanted. I will flag this question as a duplicate.